# Include Fulfilled Orders In ShopifyAPI::Order.All

Tags: ruby, shopify, shopify-app

As a part of my shopify application I would like to keep a local export of every single one of my orders. I have a ruby script that achieves most of what I need here, but it only fetches unfulfilled orders.

I have tried tweaking  ShopifyAPI::Order.all by adding parameters like so

fullfilled_orders=ShopifyAPI::Order.all(params: { status: 'any', fulfillment_status: 'fulfilled'})

I try variations of 'any' and 'fulfilled' for both fields, and even running it with no parameters, but the output stays the same.

The application has every possible permission in the store's settings page and the application scope in ruby is set to this

scope: 'read_all_orders read_orders read_customers read_users',

Here is a snippet of the function

```
def order_dl()
    # Load API credentials from file
    config = YAML.load_file('config.yml')


    # Shopify API credentials
    session = ShopifyAPI::Auth::Session.new(
    shop: config['shop'],
    access_token: config['access_token'],
    )

    ShopifyAPI::Context.setup(
    api_key: config['api_key'],
    api_secret_key: config['api_secret_key'],
    api_version: '2024-01', # Example: '2024-01'
    scope: 'read_all_orders read_orders read_customers read_users',
    is_private: false, # Set to true if you are using a private app
    is_embedded: true # Set to true if you are using an embedded app
    )

    ShopifyAPI::Context.activate_session(session)

    client = ShopifyAPI::Clients::Rest::Admin.new(
    session: session
    )
    test_session = ShopifyAPI::Context.active_session


    #retrieve order details
    orders = ShopifyAPI::Order.all(params: { status: 'any', fulfillment_status: 'any'})
    infos=[]
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @LarsNielsen I made an edit, I hope my meaning is more clear now.

Comment: PSA: In Ruby any method without arguments can have the brackets omitted, so `def order_dl` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are passing the options incorrectly. According to the [docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/Shopify/shopify_api/ShopifyAPI/Order#all-class_method) `status` and `fulfillment_status` are keyword arguments and should be passed as follows:

```
ShopifyAPI::Order.all( status: 'any', fulfillment_status: 'any')
```

Please note this will only retrieve the first 50 by default. [API Docs](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-10/resources/order#get-orders?status=any).

You can set the limit to 250 using `limit: 250`; however you cannot retrieve any more than 250 records at a time so to truly receive all of them you may have to loop this process multiple times using an offset like `since` or `updated_at_min`